# Como calcular los días entre dos fechas, sin tomar en cuenta las fechas duplicadas en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla llamada trfDespacho con FechaSalida y FechaLlegada del Empleado, lo que estoy obteniendo es la diferencia de días que hay entre las fechas pero no quiero la diferencia de los días con fechas iguales solo fechas diferentes
la línea de código que uso es la siguiente

```
Despacho= isnull(COALESCE(SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, D.FechaSalida, D.FechaLlegada) + 1), 0),0)
```

El detalle es que tengo rango de fechas duplicadas adjunto una imagen en como esta en la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al momento de obtener la diferencia me indica que tengo 3 días, como puedo hacer para que no me tome en cuenta las fechas que están duplicadas (mismo día diferente hora) y solo me indique que son 2 días el día 21 y el día 25.

**Modificado**

En la tabla de trfDespacho tengo lo siguiente:

```
select* from trfDespacho where numOperador= 450654
```

[image: tabla trfDespacho]

Con la Consulta que tengo de Count obtengo

```
select COUNT( distinct FechaSalida )
from trfDespacho D
JOIN CopCalendario CC ON CC.NumOperador = D.NumOperador
LEFT JOIN CopCalendarioIncidencias CPI on CC.idNumOperador=CPI.idNumOperador
where (CC.NumOperador = @NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0)
and FechaSalida between @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta 
group by cast(FechaSalida as date)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me regresa que de la fecha del día

- 21 al 21 tengo 2
- 23 al 24 tengo 1
- 25 al 25 tengo 1
- 26 al 27 tengo 1

Lo que quiero que me Muestre es:

- 21 al 21 Mostrar 1 (aun que tenga dos registros pero son el mismo día solo mostrar 1)
- 23 al 24 Mostrar 2 (2 porque inicia el 23 y termina 24 deseo que tome los 2 días)
- 25 al 25 Mostrar 1 (Solo mostrar 1 que es el día registrado)
- 26 al 27 Mostrar 2 (2 porque inicia el 26 y termina 25 deseo que tome los 2 días)

Como puedo lograrlo para que el total de las incidencias entonces sea 6.

**Consulta Final**

```
Con el siguiente obtengo los Días de todos los empleados que trabajan dentro del rango de las fechas especificado:

declare @numOperador int, @FechaDesde datetime, @FechaHasta datetime
set @FechaDesde='2017-05-01 00:00:00.000'
set @FechaHasta='2017-06-30 00:00:00.000'
set @numOperador=450654

;WITH FechasUnicas AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE,FechaSalida) FechaSalida, 
                    CONVERT(DATE,FechaLlegada) FechaLlegada,
                    CC.NumOperador
    FROM dbo.trfDespacho D
    JOIN CopCalendario CC ON CC.NumOperador = D.NumOperador
    where (CC.NumOperador = @NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0)
    and FechaSalida between @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta 
    group by CC.NumOperador, FechaSalida, FechaLlegada
)
SELECT DiasTrabajados=SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,FechaSalida,FechaLlegada) + 1) , NumOperador
FROM FechasUnicas
group by NumOperador
```

[image: Resultado]

Obtengo que trabaja 6 días pero deben de ser 5 ahora ya que en Fecha Salida se Repite la Fecha 26 de Mayo a 26 de Mayo Fecha Llegada y hay otro registro que esta de 26 de Mayo al 27 de Mayo entonces ahí me esta tomando 3 días y no 2 como puedo hacer para que solo me tome los 2 días que deben ser.

Comment: me suena a que para nada necesitas ver la diferencia de dias entre FechaSalida y FechaLlegada...más bien simplemente contar fechas distintas

Comment: gracias @Lamak realice un consulta la cual agrego al inicio puedes ver e indicarme como puedo ahora sumar los registros que he obtenido.

Comment: me refiero a que se ve como si sólo necesitaras usar `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT FechaSalida) FROM trfDespacho WHERE ......`

Comment: gracias por el seguimiento @Lamark agregue a mi consulta lo que tengo y lo que deseo obtener no se si puedas verla y orientarme un poco más.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, creo que el requerimiento es bastante extraño, pero el resultado lo puedes obtener de la siguiente forma:

```
;WITH FechasUnicas AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE,FechaSalida) FechaSalida, 
                    CONVERT(DATE,FechaLlegada) FechaLlegada
    FROM dbo.trfDespacho
)
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,D.FechaSalida,D.FechaLlegada) + 1)
FROM FechasUnicas;
```

Ok, éste sería el código para tu nuevo requerimiento:

```
;WITH FechasUnicas AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CC.NumOperador,
                    CONVERT(DATE,X.Fecha) Fecha
    FROM dbo.trfDespacho D
    INNER JOIN CopCalendario CC 
        ON CC.NumOperador = D.NumOperador
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
                      (D.FechaSalida),
                      (D.FechaLlegada)
                 ) x(Fecha)
    WHERE (CC.NumOperador = @NumOperador OR @NumOperador = 0)
    AND FechaSalida BETWEEN @FechaDesde AND @FechaHasta 
)
SELECT  NumOperador,
        DiasTrabajados = COUNT(DISTINCT Fecha)
FROM FechasUnicas
GROUP BY NumOperador;
```

Comment: Estoy probando como me lo indicas @Lamak pero me marca el siguiente error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: @Molitaa eso significa que pegaste el código justo después de otra consulta **la cual no la terminaste con un punto y coma**. Agregué un `;` al inicio para evitar este error, pero te recomiendo que te acostumbres a terminar cada sentencia SQL con su respectivo `;`

Comment: agradezco mucho tu apoyo @Lamak y claro que tomare en cuenta lo que me indicas para terminar cada sentencia SQL, he probado y me ha funcionando de forma correcta, en el Select que esta dentro de With he colocado la relación de las demás tablas con su Where y en ella tengo where (CC.NumOperador = NumOperador OR NumOperador = 0) si yo coloco el 0 quiero que me regrese a todos los empleados que tengo registrados con sus respectivas incidencias esto lo puedo lograr aquí mismo ? Coloco la consulta actual en la misma pregunta.

Comment: Listo ya puedo ver todos los demás Empleados colocando el número 0 gracias, ahora tengo otro Detalle al momento de mostrare los días, si un empleado tiene la Fecha 2017-05-26 06:00:00.000 al 2017-05-26 07:00:00.000 y 2017-05-26 06:00:00.000 al 2017-05-27 06:00:00.000 me cuenta que tengo 3 días cuando deben de ser solo 2 días que puedo hacer paya que solo me arroje los 2 días, en la pregunta dejare el Código actual para ver si me puedes apoyar.

Comment: *sigh*, la verdad es que deberías haber descrito las excepciones desde un principio, de forma de no tener que modificar la respuesta de esta forma. Trataré de revisar este requerimiento

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu apoyo @Lamak , me ha regresado la información que necesitaba, me di cuenta que era necesario el ultimo requerimiento hasta que lo corrí ya que me regresaba más días de lo normal es por esto que no lo había comentado, muchísimas gracias, linda tarde.

Comment: Hola @Lamak, como puedo hacer en caso de que el Empleado no tenga registros en la tabla de trfDespachos (no Fecha de Salida, noFecha Llegada) para poder mostrar numOperador y mostrar 0 días trabajados? estuve colocando isnull en caso de que el campo estuviera vacio o null pero aun así no me permite, espero me puedas apoyar.